# German Handwriting decoding request

Tags: handwriting

Handwritten message on the back of a photograph with a 1930's? uniformed policeman on the front.
Any ideas what the written says is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It reads:

> Major Fuchs
> (Kraftfahrschule der Gendarmerie)
> Suhl i. Thr. u. Berlin-Schöneberg

"Suhl i. Thr." most likely stands for the city [Suhl in Thuringia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suhl). [This article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulen_der_SS,_des_SD_und_der_Sicherheitspolizei) mentions the [SD](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicherheitsdienst_des_Reichsf%C3%BChrers_SS) Driving School was at Suhl.

Comment: Well, to be entirely historically correct, the School in Suhl was the *Gendarmerie-Kraftfahrschule* (that is, a "normal" police institution) which was only merged into the SD in 1939. Fuchs led that school only until 1938.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I would really like to know how you managed to read that - it was not obvious :-) Helps a lot !!